# Show a DIV after Page Redirect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that is set to `hide()` when `document` is ready. I want this div to appear when the containing div becomes visible. I also have a form that accepts user input. The form is redirected to its page, `action ="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"`. The **submit** has a class `.submitRecord`. The containing div becomes visible upon successful submission of record to DB.

**PHP Code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submitRecord']) && $success != ''){
    echo "<div class='containingDiv'>";
       echo "<div class='alloc'>";
         echo "<p class = 'closeButton'> x </p>";
         echo "<p class = 'allocationSuccess'>Allocation Successful for Mr/Mrs ABC</p>";
       echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    };
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.containingDiv, .alloc').hide();
  $(document).on('click', '#saveRecord', function () { 
    if ($(".containingDiv").is(':visible')){
        $('.alloc').slideDown(500);
    }
  });
 $(document).on('click', '.closeButton', function () { 
    $('.alloc').hide(500);
  });
});
```

The form get submitted and `var` `$success` is assigned a string but `.alloc` won't show.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: check first this  `$('.alloc').show()`

Comment: @hellosheikh I don't want it shown in the first instance. I worked on it well before setting to hidden.

Comment: @jeroen: Not using AJAX. It reloads the page. I don't want to use AJAX to this. How can I achieve without AJAX?

Comment: @Yax See the second option of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your title, you are using a normal form submit (no ajax). That means that the flow of events is like:

- Your button is clicked;
- Your javascript function is triggered, trying to animate a `div` that is not on the page;
- The visitor gets redirected to the page to where the form is submitted, even if there was an animation, the visitor will not see it because of the redirect;
- The form is processed and a new page is shown (no javascript onClick events have been triggered here);
- The success `div` is added to the page but remains hidden.

There are two solutions:

1. You submit the form using ajax, keep everything in the same page and animate what you want to;
2. You show - and don't hide on page-load - the succes box on your success page and you only hide it after a certain `timeOut` or button click. Note that you do not have to hide the box on page load as it is only added to the page on a successful form submit.

Comment: @jereon: Thank you but if I show it and hide on `timeOut` how will it solve my problem?

Comment: @Yax It will show your success message only on a successful form submit and hide it automatically after some time. But you can stick to your button as well.